# How can you declare a global variable inside a function ? How do you make sure it remembers that value so you can use it in another function?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I would like to declare a global variable inside a function as you can see from the following example:

```
int global_variable;

void function(int x, int y) {
    x = 58;
    y = 71;
    global_variable = x + y; // declare global variable inside function
}

int main(int z) {
    z = global_variable + 75;
    printf("result: %d \n", z);
}
```

The result is `0` here when I want it to be `204` as the sum of `x` and `y` and `z`.
How do I make sure that the global variable is remembered when called in another function?

Comment: 1) the signature for `main` is incorrect, and 2) `function` is never called.

Comment: Relevant to `global_variable = x + y; // declare global variable inside function`: This is not a declaration. This is an assignment.

Comment: It's nonsensical to pass `x` and `y` as parameters to `function ()` and then immediately assign values to them.  Your 'declaration' in `function()` is not a declaration at all; it is a simple assignment.  That assignment will only be executed if you call `function()`.  The code shown should be printing `75`, not `0`.

Comment: The lesson learnt here is that you can't do C programming by guessing. You have to actually study how functions and variables work in some decent learning material like a book, before attempting to use them. There is no such thing as "trial & error" when learning programming.

Comment: @chqrlie: you should not edit the placement of braces unless they are outrageously wrong (and even then, you should think carefully).  Using Allman style is a legitimate choice; you should not impose 1TBS on the code.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a prank ... if not I will make it quick. I hope this example is more clear what you was doing wrong.
You can also try your code here:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

```
int global_variable; // initialized with default -> 0
void function(int x, int y)
{
    global_variable = x + y; // add x and y to your global_variable
}

int main()
{

    function(71, 58);
    printf("result: %d \n", global_variable);
    global_variable += 75
    printf("result: %d \n", global_variable);
}
```